# Terminate process upon specific output

Tags: command-line, process, output, process-management

How can I terminate a process upon specific output from that process? For example, running a Java program with `java -jar xyz.jar`, I want to terminate the process once the line "Started server on port 8000" appears on stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be accomplished with the following script considering that `grep -m1` doesn't work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar xyz.jar &> "/tmp/yourscriptlog.txt" &
processnumber=$!
tail -F "/tmp/yourscriptlog.txt" | awk  '/Started server on port 8000/ { system("kill '$processnumber'") }'
```

Basically, this script redirects the `stdout` of your java code to a file with the command`&> "/tmp/yourscriptlog.txt"`, the last  `&` on the first line makes your code run as an isolated process and on the next line we have the number of this process with `$!`. Having the number of the process and a log file to `tail` we can finally kill the process when the desired line is printed.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Was able to get this script itself to exit as well by replacing the awk command with `grep -m1 'Started server on port 8000' && kill $processnumber`

Answer (score 1):

```
java -jar xyz.jar | grep -m1 "Started server on port 8000"
```

Comment: For environments with GNU grep (which adds `-m`).

Comment: This does not seem to work, at least for the application I'm running. The grepped line will come out but the application continues to run. Apparently SIGPIPE is not handled here to indicate the program should terminate

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted the answer of @Rafael for more complicated occasions like mine, were the script won't simply let itself be pushed to the background.

Open a first `tmux` session and put your command (use `tee` instead of redirection to see output live), then detach with Ctrl-B D:

```
java -jar xyz.jar &> '/var/log/myscript.log'
```

In another tmux session, handle the termination:

```
tail -F '/var/log/myscript.log' | awk '/Started server on port 8000/ { system("tmux kill-session -t 0") }'
```

Use a named session if you already have other running tmux sessions.